# Building JasperMobile with Eclipse/Maven for Android

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, maven, symlink

I am currently have to build a mobile client for the Jaspersoft Report Server on android. In order to do so I got the source code of the existing open source JasperMobile app, thinking I could use this as a basis/template and extend it with the specific features our company needs. After sorting out a ton of build problems I am stuck with one last one:

When building I get the following output from maven:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building js-android-jaspermobile 1.5
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ js-android-jaspermobile ---
    [INFO] Deleting C:\Development\JasperMobile\target
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.3.0:generate-sources
    (default-generate-sources) @ js-android-jaspermobile ---
    [DEBUG] Expanding: c:\DEVELOPMENT\maven\repo\com\actionbarsherlock\actionbarsherlock\4.3.1
    \actionbarsherlock-4.3.1.apklib into C:\Development\JasperMobile\target\unpack\apklibs
    \com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.3.1
    [DEBUG] expand complete
    [INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
    [INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
    [INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 3.767s
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 09 14:49:37 CAT 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/11M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-
    plugin:3.3.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project js-android-
    jaspermobile: Execution default-generate-sources of goal
    com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.3.0:generate-sources 
    failed: Could not find tool 'aapt'. Please provide a proper Android SDK directory path as 
    configuration parameter <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> in the plugin <configuration/>. As an 
    alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline: -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set 
    environment variable ANDROID_HOME. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
    following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I have read up about this problem and it appears to be related to the eclipse plug-in used to integrate maven with android development. It looks for aapt.exe and aidl.exe in \platform-tools\ instead of \build-tools\. The current work-around seems to be to make symlinks (using mklink as admin in win7) for the necessary files, but when linking an executable I get a broken file instead of a link, even though according to cmd the operation is successful.

Please I am a mavin and windoze n00b so if there maybe is another workaround? maybe point maven to the correct location? some other tool for symlinking?

Thanks all!

Comment: If this is failing on the command line as the above output log indicates, then this probably isn't a problem with the eclipse plug-in used to integrate maven with android development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the issue with maven-android-plugin and latest android ADT from Google:
https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=380

It was fixed in v 3.6.0, so you just need to update you android-maven-plugin to this version:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    ...
</plugin>
```